# ArangoDB Create Graph from edges and documents

Tags: collections, document, arangodb, edges

I have created an edge collection , and I read that the collection should point to documents .
As documents I have created a dcument collection this collection has as a schema :
("Entry","name","reference")
the reference attribute is the key that link the documents to the schema found in the edges document .

How do I make that clear to arangoDB to create the graph ?

I don't see how to do it